# Output text to .innerHTML repeatedly using Javascript while loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, while-loop

I'm learning how to use while loops, and although I more or less have the concept down I'm having some trouble getting a while loop to write text repeatedly to an html element.

```js
var text = prompt("What would you like logged to screen?");
//I may need to convert prompt output to a number
var repeatText = prompt("How many times would you like to print the text?");
var loopCount = 0;

while (loopCount < repeatText) {
 //I want text to print out on screen "x" times, where x is equal to the numerical value of loopCount
  document.getElementById("outputHolder2").innerHTML += text;
  loopcount++;
}

//this isn't outputting to outputHolder1 after loop
document.getElementById("outputHolder1").innerHTML = loopCount;
```

```css
#outputHolder1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 5;
}

#outputHolder2 {
  padding: 2% 10% 0% 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="outputHolder1">
    NUMBER OF TIMES TO LOOP:
  </p>

  <p id="outputHolder2">

  </p>

</div>
```

From what I understand, `.innerHTML += text` *should* copy the inner text of an HTML element, and add new text to it, however I haven't been able to make this work in a loop.

Raw Javascript solutions only please.

Comment: Beware though that you need to ensure that the input is valid HTML; otherwise you'll run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says "`loopcount` is undefined" when you access it. Your variable is `loopCount`. **Remember: JavaScript is case-sensitive.**

Also, yes, you should convert the user input from the `prompt` to a number. You can do a comparison without doing this, but it is a good best-practice in case you decide to do other math with the value later on in code.

```js
var text = prompt("What would you like logged to screen?");

// I may need to convert prompt output to a number
var repeatText = parseInt(prompt("How many times would you like to print the text?"), 10);

var loopCount = 0;

while (loopCount < repeatText) {
  // I want text to print out on screen "x" times, 
  // where x is equal to the numerical value of loopCount
  document.getElementById("outputHolder2").innerHTML += text;
  loopCount++;
}

// this isn't outputting to outputHolder1 after loop
document.getElementById("outputHolder1").innerHTML = loopCount;
```

```css
#outputHolder1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 5;
}

#outputHolder2 {
  padding: 2% 10% 0% 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="outputHolder1">
    NUMBER OF TIMES TO LOOP:
  </p>

  <p id="outputHolder2">

  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Well owl be damned. I've been staring at this for a good hour and didn't even notice a simple typo.

Also, I'm aware of the parseInt() function from doing my own research however I'm don't quite understand the radix yet. (although it seems to work without it.)

Comment: @ShawnR. The "radix" is provided so that the JavaScript engine knows what base numeral system you are using. This is important because if the user's input begins with "0", the base system will be considered as octal (base 8) and if the string starts with "0x", hex (base 16) will be assumed. So by putting `10` in, you are telling the JS engine to get the number as a base 10 number.

Answer (score 3):

The `loopcount++;` should be in *CamelCase* like you've defined in the first time `var loopCount = 0;` :

```
loopCount++;
```

Else it will be considered as *`undefined`* variable `loopcount`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var text = prompt("What would you like logged to screen?");
var repeatText = prompt("How many times would you like to print the text?");
var loopCount = 0;

while (loopCount < repeatText) {
  document.getElementById("outputHolder2").innerHTML += text;
  loopCount++;
}

document.getElementById("outputHolder1").innerHTML = loopCount;
```

```css
#outputHolder1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 5;
}

#outputHolder2 {
  padding: 2% 10% 0% 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="outputHolder1">
    NUMBER OF TIMES TO LOOP:
  </p>
  <p id="outputHolder2"></p>
</div>
```